# How do I generate a mesh gradient?

Tags: python, image, gradient

I want to create a mesh gradient from some random points and colours similar to https://csshero.org/mesher/.

It's pretty trivial to interpolate between two colours using the method on https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/01/06/colour-interpolation/ although the issue I have is I don't know how to interpolate between multiple colours in two dimensions like this. Any pseudo-code/python of how to interpolate between colours like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the interp2d function from scipy : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html